# convert and concatenate multiple FormGroup types to object type in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular

Im using mat-stepper of Angular Material design library.

I use 3 separate FormGroups. I would send informations to database using httpClient method, for that I have created an interface :

```
export interface NouveauProjet {
    leadProj: String ;
    nomProj: String;
    descProj: String;
    besProj: Number;
    pers: [Personnes];
    Backlog: [Fonctionnalite]
}

export interface Personnes {
    name: String;
    poste:String
}
export interface Fonctionnalite {
    fonctionnalite: String;
    userStory: String 
}
```

In my component file I create forms and `nouveauProject` variable that will contain my values .

```
export class AjoutProjetComponent implements OnInit {
  isLinear = false;
  firstFormGroup: FormGroup;
  secondFormGroup: FormGroup;
  thirdFormGroup: FormGroup;
  nouveauProjet: NouveauProjet;
  constructor(
    private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private ajoutProj: AjoutprojService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log();
    this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      leadProj: ["", Validators.required],
      nomProj: ["", Validators.required],
      descProj: ["", Validators.required],
      besProj: ["", Validators.required]
    });
    this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      pers: this._formBuilder.array([this.createItem()])
    });

    this.thirdFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      backlog: this._formBuilder.array([this.createFonct()])
    });
  }

  createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this._formBuilder.group({
      name: ["", Validators.required],
      poste: ["", Validators.required]
    });
  }

  createFonct(): FormGroup {
    return this._formBuilder.group({
      fonctionnalite: ["", Validators.required],
      userStory: ["", Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

I call my service and before I concatenate formGroup.value.

```
  addProjet() {
    this.nouveauProjet =
      this.firstFormGroup.value +
      this.secondFormGroup.value +
      this.thirdFormGroup.value;
    console.log(this.nouveauProjet);
    this.ajoutProj
      .addProj(this.nouveauProjet)
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.json);
      });
  }
}
```

In html file I call `addProject` function then I print `{{nouveaProjet | json}}`  value I get this :

```
"[object Object][object Object][object Object]"
```

How to print all values ?

**Update:** this.firstFormGroup.value, this.secondFormGroup.value, this.thirdFormGroup.value  gives in order  :

[image: values of FormGroup]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Object cannot be concatenated with `+` so you could try:

Old way:

```
var __assign = (this && this.__assign) || Object.assign || function(t) {
  for (var s, i = 1, n = arguments.length; i < n; i++) {
    s = arguments[i];
      for (var p in s) if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(s, p))
        t[p] = s[p];
    }
    return t;
};
this.nouveauProjet = __assign(this.firstFormGroup.value, this.secondFormGroup.value, this.thirdFormGroup.value);
```

Using ES6 [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
this.nouveauProjet = {
      ...this.firstFormGroup.value,
      ...this.secondFormGroup.value,
      ...this.thirdFormGroup.value
};
```

Comment: i get this error : `ERROR in src/app/ajout-projet/ajout-projet.component.ts(72,31): error TS1005: ':' expected.` 3 times

Comment: @HamzaHaddad can you provide an example of what `this.firstFormGroup.value`, `this.secondFormGroup.value` and `this.thirdFormGroup.value` give.

Comment: I havn't add the three dots when I copied your solution, now it works. What does the three dots ?

Comment: @HamzaHaddad you can read more about the es6 spread operator here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161181/discussion-between-ayoub-and-hamza-haddad).